# Using lambdas to decouple the client code

Tags: design-patterns, solid

The [ISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) says that the client should not depend on things what are not needed. As a solution small focusing interfaces (contracts) can be used:

```
interface RegisterUser {
  User register(String username);
}

class UserService implements RegisterUser,LockUser,FindUser,... {
  ...
}

class UserRegistrationClient {
  private RegisterUser registerUser;
  ...
}

new UserRegistrationClient(userService);
```

While this approach decouples client from unnecessary details, it brings some complexity in form of explosion of interfaces.

Similar effect can be achieved using lambdas:

```
class UserService {
  User register(String username) { ... }
  ...
}

class UserRegistrationClient {
  private Function<String,User> registerUser;
  ...
}

new UserRegistrationClient(
  username -> userService.register(username)
);
// or just:
new UserRegistrationClient(userService::register);
```

Is this a good approach or are there some design flaws I can't see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using lambdas / anonymous functions instead of interfaces with a single method (for dependency injection) is a standard approach. It is not a "good" or "bad" approach, it is an approach. And as almost any approach, it has benefits and drawbacks.

The benefits are mostly "less code" (or as you wrote, no "explosion of interfaces"). The drawbacks are less explictness / less typesafety. By using an interface, "registering service functions" get an explicit name (`RegisterUser`). Using lambdas will allow to inject any function into `UserRegistrationClient` which fits to the expected signature, not just derivations of `RegisterUser`.

What to choose depends on the specific situation, the specific requirements, and sometimes the specific taste of the programmer. It is pretty much the same decision whether one uses a `string` variable for something like a city name, or introducing a special type for city names, to distinguish them from other strings.

Comment: The flexibility and decoupling of the service provider seems to be a great benefit to me, as one doesn't have to modify the provider's code in order to implement a new function (it is sometimes even impossible when one doesn't have the provider's code in the hand). On the other hand, the explicit contract is lost as the providers has no ideal about the clients (is not forced to implement any interfaces). As you said, it's context-dependent. I just wanted to make sure that there are no flaws I didn't see (e.g. this was a well-know antipattern already, etc.). Many thanks, Doc!

Comment: The Labda approach doesn't seem to be very common at this point in time. When working in a team I would definately discuss this approach before implementing it. +1 nontheless.

Comment: @RikD: that is probably because in Java, C# and C++ lambdas were introduced much later than interfaces / abstract classes. So most text books which introduce dependency injection demonstrate it with interfaces. Actually, not allowing to use lambdas for depency injection in a team is pretty equivalent of not using lambdas at all. If you are going to forbid the usage of standard language features which were available for years (!) in a team, you will need a really serious justification, not just "I feel uncomfortable because I am not used to it".

Comment: I agree and I don't mean it shouldn't be allowed. However when lamdas for DI are introduced into an existing code base that uses the more traditional interface approach, a PR might be rejected because "that's not how we do things around here". In order to prevent that, communication with the team is (as always) important.

Comment: in the functional world while you can define a new type for the function youd probably push your types down into the parameters of the function so you get the benefit without the drawback

Comment: @jk. I still see a drawback in losing the duplex contract as the provider is not forced to implement any interface anymore.